# SQL WHERE insert

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have this snippet:

```
SELECT Recording_artist.artist_name,Musical_genre.musical_genre,
COUNT(Musical_genre.musical_genre) AS Songs
FROM Recording_artist
FULL OUTER JOIN Album
ON Recording_artist.recording_artist_id = Album.recording_artist_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Song
ON Album.album_id = Song.album_id
INNER JOIN Musical_genre
ON Album.musical_genre_id = Musical_genre.musical_genre_id
GROUP BY Recording_artist.artist_name,Musical_genre.musical_genre;
```

I need to put a `WHERE musical_genre = 'Rock'`, but it seems oracle doesnt want me to put that in anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you want?:

```
SELECT Recording_artist.artist_name,Musical_genre.musical_genre,
    COUNT(Musical_genre.musical_genre) AS Songs
FROM Recording_artist
    FULL OUTER JOIN Album
        ON Recording_artist.recording_artist_id = Album.recording_artist_id
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN Song
        ON Album.album_id = Song.album_id
    INNER JOIN Musical_genre
        ON Album.musical_genre_id = Musical_genre.musical_genre_id
WHERE Musical_genre.musical_genre = 'Rock'
GROUP BY Recording_artist.artist_name,Musical_genre.musical_genre;
```

and, this question has mysql tag. but seems like Oracle question.

Comment: hold on a minute here, you mean to tell me indentation matters? I put your indented version in and it seems to work. Wow ok

Comment: @user3015045 oop! indentation is not a problem. I added `WHERE` before GROUP BY. ;-)

Comment: but I did that before and i got an error? And yes I forgot to tag as Oracle.